# GetWidenedPathGeometry without Polygonal Approximation

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, geometry, pathgeometry

Currently in my project, I use WPF methods like Geometry.GetWidenedPathGeometry and Geometry.GetOutlinedPathGeometry to obtain the outlines for some PathGeometries.

However, these resulting geometries usually are formed by a PolyLineSegment, due to the polygonal approximation method that is used in WPF.

This means that if my original PathGeometry contains an ArcSegment, the resulting outline will be a series of polygon points (with adjustable tolerance) instead of an ArcSegment.

I am looking for alternatives to produce the same result the methods mentioned produce, but keeping the original geometry types used.

Thank you,

Igor.